# Rails_admin: How to create a navigation link to selected items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

User can send the personal info for verification.
Admin can review user's info and send feedback to user.

I created field named "state" in User model which represents the current state of verification.

I need to put the link to dashboard for all entries with state = "unconfirmed". Is there a way?

This is how I tried:

*User.rb:*

```
scope :unconfirmed, -> { where(state: 'unconfirmed') }
```

*initializers/rails_admin.rb*

```
config.navigation_static_links = {
  'Need to be checked' => User.unconfirmed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this -

show link on dashboard list page / ##replace below code as per your requirments

```
config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
member :action_name do
  register_instance_option :link_icon do
    'icon-pencil'
   end

  register_instance_option :pjax? do
    false
  end

  visible do
    bindings[:abstract_model].model.to_s == "User" && bindings[:object].present? && bindings[:object].state.eql?("unconfirmed")
  end
end
```